# Границы формы C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Как убрать внутренний отступ от границ формы ? Он составляет примерно 1 пиксель..т.е если ставишь любой элемент, например, кнопку и прижимаешь её к краю формы, то видно этот самый 1-2 пиксель границы формы. FormBorderStyle = None, но это не помогает

Comment: Чтобы лучше понимать о чем идет речь, вот скрин. Залил на Я. диск.
https://yadi.sk/i/d0w5KYsRgSVTP

Comment: Если вы хотите дизайн, то мой вам совет, переходите на WPF!

Comment: 0. Картинки можно (и в подобных случаях нужно) вставлять в сам вопрос. 1. Прикрепите код инициализации контрола и формы, чтобы мы точно знали, какие им заданы характеристики. 2. Поддерживаю комментарий про WPF

Comment: Да, я знаю про WPF..но мне было бы очень интересно..возможно ли это, или нет без стороннего фреймворка

Comment: Плохо знаете, раз пишете на WinForms дизайн. Не получится у вас там нечего годного, увы, либо потратите уйму времени. Ну а по поводу вопроса, не воспроизводиться. Вот вам [форма](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdDMj.png) с установленным `FormBorderStyle = None`, с красным задним фоном. Поверх панель, растянутая с помощью `Dock = Fill;` и синей заливкой. Как видите нет каких либо "внутренних отступов от границ формы" в стандартно WinForms приложении.

Comment: [Margin and Padding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/margin-and-padding-in-windows-forms-controls) - обратите внимание на эти свойства в первую очередь

Comment: Margin & paddin = 0
Dock = Fill дает то, что нужно. Но я не собирался вроде как заливать форму цветом..установите Dock = Left, например, и будет пиксельный отступ. WPF мне в принципе не нужен для формы из 2х - 3х кнопок..абсурдно я бы сказал..дольше в WPF со стилями провожусь. А тут и интересная ситуация, и нестандартные способы решения как по мне )

Comment: Заливку формы я лишь показал для наглядности. Если выступает красный цвет, то значит есть отступ, в моем варианте его не было. Вот вам [тоже самое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4t0b.png) (цвет только другой), но с `Dock = Left`.Отступа по прежнему нет. Что касается WPF, тут дело не в скорости, а в возможностях и доступности этих возможностей. Для того, что бы сделать к примеру [такой макет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpaER.jpg) (со всеми анимациями, тенями, переходами), мне понадобилось пару часов в WPF, сделать такое в WinForms у меня лично ушло бы пару дней и не думаю, что сделал бы такое.

Comment: А вы помимо borderstyle и dock у формы и panel производите какие либо доп.  настройки ? мб кодом или непосредственно в студии..у меня почему то рисуется эта линия..ставлю другой фреймворк - нет линии..но Фреймворк не хочется юзать. Даже принудительно при запуске формы кодом прописал обнуление padding, margin и убрал границы у элементов..

Comment: Пустой проект, пустая форма, настроек нет, лишь описанные. Попробуйте сами на пустом проекте, найдите то, что вам мешает. P.S. Если хотите оповестить кого либо, то не забывайте указать его ник через @.